# Opening a New Custom Window From Other in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have two customized NSWindow in my application like these:

***Window 1:***

```
public partial class LoginVindow : NSWindow
    {
        public LoginVindow (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }
    }
```

[image: Window 1]

***Window 2:***

```
public partial class OperationWindow : NSWindow
    {
        public OperationWindow (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }
    }
```

[image: Window 2]

Now, I want close the first Window after a button click and open the second Window. However, this code cannot run for me.

```
 partial void LoginButton_Clicked(Foundation.NSObject sender)
    {
        Window.Close(); // Closes the first login window.

        var operation_window = new OperationWindow(Handle); // Gets the second Window. IntPtr parameter is required unlike the internet codeblocks.

        operation_window.ShowWindow(this); // No any method like this.
    }
```

All of the code blocks over internet seems for non-customized standard class NSWindow items but one of them is seems stable for me. However, it is not running. (Post in Xamarin Forums: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/122359/open-and-close-window-programmatically-xamarin-mac)

How can I handle this operation ? Please help, thanks.

Comment: You do not `ShowWindow` via the NSWindow itself, you show it via the a `NSWindowController` as the NSWindow is owned by the NSWindowController ( `yourWindowController.ShowWindow(yourAppDel);`)

Comment: How can I define a NSWindowController via Code? For example, the Window 1 is the starting point and show automatically by app. Is it a automatic Window controller? @SushiHangover

Comment: Also, the constructor wants IntPtr input for me like: LoginWindowController (IntPtr handle). I cannot solve how can I make the controller live. Which type of IntPtr should I use ? @SushiHangover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code block fixed my problem. Thanks.

```
    // Get new window
    var storyboard = NSStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
    var controller = storyboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier("OperationsWindow") as NSWindowController;
    controller.ShowWindow(this);
    this.Window.Close();
```